# Integer numbers processing

Tags: java, processing

Can someone please give me starting point for a program in Processing which should add all integer numbers from 1 to 100 and prints the result.

I appreciate any help.

Kind regards...

Comment: There is a formula for the sum of N natural numbers just use it.

Comment: And the starting point is ... `public static void main(String args[])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways you can do this. A simple ways is adding all values in a loop:

```
    int n = 100;

    int result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        result += i;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Or as @nullpointer mentioned, you can use a formula to calculate the result:

```
    int n = 100;

    int result = (n * (n+1)) / 2;

    System.out.println(result);
```

Ok as mentioned in the comments: if you only want to add even numbers you can change it to this:

```
    int n = 3;

    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            result += i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support

Comment: Or `for(int i = 0; i <= n; i = i+2)` without if.

Comment: @Eritrean yes in this case that would also work, but I prefer checking it with % because if you change the starting point (for example when you want to count all even numbers from 3 to 15) then you wouldn't get the desired result because incrementing by two would then result in listing only odd numbers

Comment: Please consider the fact that you just did somebody's homework for them.